# How to add a new row to Excel file using unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, windows, excel, unmanaged

How can I add a new row (with contents) to an existing Excel .xls file using unmanaged C++ running on Windows?

I don't mind using OLE, COM, or any external free library, whatever is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a COM interface which is [well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

I'd suggest you start with the [`Workbooks.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb179167%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method to open an existing excel file.

If you only need basic features (no formatting, formula's, ...), you can also use [BasicExcel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/BasicExcel.aspx): A c++ library which doesn't have any dependencies (it reads and writes the excel file as a compound file) and is much easier to use than the COM interface (at least from c++).

Answer (score 0):

I've used SQL to do this.  I don't have sample code handy, but a quick google search brought this up:  [Link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/60599-reading-excel-sheet-data-and-sheet-name-and-transfer-to-sql-data-base/)

Hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restrictions to use managed libraries you can check [NPOI](http://code.google.com/p/npoi/), a managed library to handle Excel file format.

Since it is managed it should be possible to register it as a COM server. If, for any reason, it proves hard/impossible to register it as a COM server you can write a thin COM server (either in C++ or C# or whatever you prefer) to expose just the functionality you need to your unmanaged C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this one: [ExcelFormatLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/ExcelFormat.aspx), it's great and simple to use, C++, well maintained, compiles and works without any trouble.